# npm pusher and fetch not working with webpack

Tags: reactjs, fetch, pusher, spring-bean

I am using spring-boot as my back end and reactjs for front end and here is the code(not sharing complete code)

Here is my Controller Class

```
@RestController
@SessionAttributes(GeneralConstants.ID_SESSION_SHOPPING_CART)
public class CartController {

    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    private Pusher pusher;


    @PostConstruct
    public void configure() {
        pusher = new Pusher(
                PusherConstants.PUSHER_APP_ID, 
                PusherConstants.PUSHER_APP_KEY, 
                PusherConstants.PUSHER_APP_SECRET
        );
        pusher.setCluster("ap2");
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(1L);
        product.setName("Office Chair");
        product.setPrice(new BigDecimal("55.99"));
        products.add(product);


    }

    /**
     * Method that returns the products available for shopping
     * 
     * @return List of product objects
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/products", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET,  
            produces = "application/json")
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
```

Here is my entry class for react code

```
var App  = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { items: [], products: [] };
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
      alert("snake2ee")
    this.pusher = new Pusher(arg1, {
      encrypted: true,
      cluster: 'ap2',
    });
    this.channel = this.pusher.subscribe(arg2);
    this.total = 0;
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    fetch('/products').then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(this.getProductsSuccess);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {

    // Unbind from channel events
    this.channel.unbind();

    // Unsubscribe from the Pusher channel
    this.pusher.unsubscribe(this.channel);

    // Unregister by assign them to an empty function
    this.getProductsSuccess = function() {};

  },
  getProductsSuccess: function(response) {
      alert("in success")

    this.setState({
        products: response
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header products={this.state.products} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

My code is working fine if i use cdn for react,pusher and fetch.My Problem is i want to use react-toolbox and there is no cdn available for the same so i decided to move to webpack and ignore the use of cdn.But i faced some problems and did not come up with any solution after wasting a lot of time

```
npm pusher and fetch are not working in webpack
```

Please guide.Thanks:)

Comment: "I faced some problems" - what problems did you face? If you can describe them we may be able to help.

Comment: if i use    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.1/fetch.js"></script>
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.0/pusher.min.js"></script> in my html file then pusher and fetch works as my action in spring controller fires an event and that event gets caught in my react class and hence it works using cdn.But if i use npm dependency ie import Pusher from "pusher" then it does not work.Hope you get it

Comment: You need to be more specific about "does not work". What did you expect to happen? What actually happened?

Comment: obviously i expected the same behaviour that was happening before ie it should catch the events fired in my controller class but it did not.So is there something i need to do to make pusher work using webpack except installing the npm pusher dependency?